# How to use below css as inline for table row (tr)?

Tags: css, html-table

I want to apply below css as inline to tr directly , which is generated through a loop.

```
#salesbycategory > tbody > tr:nth-child(even){
            background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        #salesbycategory > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: #DDDDDD !important;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
```

Something like

```
<tr style="nth-child(even){background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
                font-weight: bold;
            }"></tr>
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: It isn't possible to create inline styles with pseudoselectors. You would need to use CSS or JS to generate the styles.

Comment: Please remove !important in background-color property. May be it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x++;

$class = ($x%2 == 0)? 'whiteBackground': 'graybackground';

echo "";

?>
It basically checks to see if $x is divisible evenly by 2. If it is, it is even.

Comment: if answers is useful then please vote and mark as green

Answer (score 0):

Inline styles are per-element, so you would have to inject the appropriate styles into the style attribute of every other tr element. If you're not already generating these rows dynamically, and you cannot use JavaScript to inject these styles, then you're stuck with having to manually apply the attribute on each tr element.

Comment: I want to send mail through PHP which has table, and as we can not use css classes while sending mail.So any idea how should I implement this?